# jQuery Rateyo rating plugin integration with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to integrate the [Rateyo plugin](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/) with AngularJS and getting problem in defined rating value from directive, following are codes:

**EDIT: Here is the working [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/K8mItqe42jNvDPs3GjyV/)**

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
   $http.get("http://mynahcare.info/frontendapi/hospital_list")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.HospitalList;});  
});
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive("rateYo", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            rating: "="
        },
        template: "<div id='rateYo'></div>",
        link: function( scope, ele, attrs ) {
            $(ele).rateYo({
                rating: String("{{scope.rating}}"),
                starWidth: "20px",      
                ratedFill: "#ffce59",
                readOnly: true          
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**And this is the HTML code**

```
<li ng-repeat="y in names | limitTo: 6"> <a href="<?php echo $this->config->item('search_url');?>{{y.hosurl}}">
  <div class="hospital-card">
    <div class="hospital-card-img-holder">
      <div class="hospital-card-img" style="background-image:url({{y.profile_image}});"></div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="vlcc-name" title="{{y.clinic_title}}">{{y.clinic_name}}</h3>
    <!--Rating begin-->
    <div class="doc-rete">
      <div rate-yo class="mc-doc-rating"></div>
    </div>
    <!--Rating ends-->
    <p class="hospital-specialist">{{y.rating }} {{y.localty }} {{y.city }}</p>
    <p class="vlcc-experince">{{y.clinic_type }}</p>
    <p class="vlcc-address">{{y.hos_time }} </p>
  </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Error in the console is **Invalid Rating, expected value between 0 and 5**

But if you see the API, the data is in number, can somebody please see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: can you give it as a working plunker??. Also you want exactly the same one alternatives!

Comment: @Arvind I will be sharing the plunker/Jsfiddle url shortly, I would prefer if  Rateyo works but dont mind if its alternate as well

Comment: @Aravind here is the working plunker : https://embed.plnkr.co/K8mItqe42jNvDPs3GjyV/

Comment: Try using .success instead of .then.

Comment: @Aravind tried your code but not working, even in plunker, it should colored stars, right now its grey start

Comment: @stormec56 tried with .success instead of .then but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>
    <style>
.hospital_listing_front > ul > li{display: block; float:left; padding:0 10px; border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
.hospital_listing_front > ul > li > a{ text-decoration:none;}
.hospital_listing_front > ul > li > a:active, .hospital_listing_front > ul > li > a:hover { text-decoration:none;}
.doc-rete {float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 20px 0;}
.hospital-card-img{width:100%; height:150px; float:left; padding:30px 0;}
.hospital-card-img > img{width:100px; height:100px; margin:0 auto; display:block;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
      <div class="container-fluid section-hospital">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row quiz-bmi">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3>List data </h3>
              <div class="carousel hospital_listing_front">
                <ul class="slides">
                  <li ng-repeat="y in names | limitTo: 3">
                    <div class="hospital-card">
                      <div class="hospital-card-img-holder">
                        <div class="hospital-card-img">
                          <img src="{{y.profile_image}}" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <h3 class="vlcc-name" title="{{y.clinic_title}}">{{y.clinic_name}}</h3>
                      <div class="doc-rete">
                        <rate-yo rating="y.rating" class="mc-doc-rating"></rate-yo>
                      </div>
                      <p class="hospital-specialist">{{y.rating }} {{y.localty }} {{y.city }}</p>
                      <p class="vlcc-experince">{{y.clinic_type }}</p>
                      <p class="vlcc-address">{{y.hos_time }} </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
   $http.get("https://mynahcare.com/frontendapi/hospital_list")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.HospitalList;});  

});
app.directive("rateYo", function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        rating: "="
    },
    template: "<div id='rateYo'></div>",
    link: function( scope, ele, attrs ) {
        $(ele).rateYo({
            rating: scope.rating,
            starWidth: "20px",      
            ratedFill: "#ffce59",
            readOnly: true          
        });
    }
  };
});
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Make your directive "rateYo" as Element so you can pass value of "rating" through attribute and it can be accessed in directive scope.

Please make following changes to resolve your issue

In directive

```
app.directive("rateYo", function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        rating: "="
    },
    template: "<div id='rateYo'></div>",
    link: function( scope, ele, attrs ) {
        $(ele).rateYo({
            rating: scope.rating,
            starWidth: "20px",      
            ratedFill: "#ffce59",
            readOnly: true          
        });
    }
  };
});
```

In HTML replace

```
<div rate-yo="" class="mc-doc-rating"></div>
```

With

```
<rate-yo rating="y.rating" class="mc-doc-rating"></rate-yo>
```